# .htaccess redirecting /contact to contact.png in root public_html folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file in the root directory of the public_html folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?codeliger\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(index\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php?page=home [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/?$ /index.php?page=edit [L]
RewriteRule ^education/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^skills/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^projects/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^experience/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=4 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact?/$ /index.php?page=contact [L]
```

This is the link I am clicking to get to my contact page:

```
<li><a href="http://codeliger.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

When I click my navigation link it navigates me to:

```
http://codeliger.com/contact.png
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to presence of [`MultiViews option`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html).

Add this line on **top of your .htaccess**:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  Problem is here.. `RewriteRule ^contact?/$ /index.php?page=contact [L]`

```
                                        ^
```

change this line

```
RewriteRule ^contact?/$ /index.php?page=contact [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /index.php?page=contact [L]
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't catch that error at first. But even after I changed it I can still not get it to work. I cleared browser cache and still the image shows up.

Comment: are you having contact.png file in root directory ?

Comment: I renamed the page to form, and changed the HTACCESS to form, and it works, but when I navigate to codeliger.com/contact it still goes to the image!!! So confusing!

Comment: try removing the contact.png or move it to another dir/

Comment: Enable the rewrite log, and then take a look what is going on. Also ensure that you don't have mime/content auto-negotiating enabled. Contact the system administrator of that server for details or contact the vendor for your support options. Configuration manual is here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/